# TortoiseSVN Find When Revision Applied to Production

Tags: svn

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.3 Build 27038.

I am currently working in an environment where there was a change to the code in 2014, according to the SVN log, but I did not start until a year later. It is possible the change has been sitting there in the repository until now and when I did a current update to production thinking only my changes where going in that change when in also.

I would like to know what date that revision was actually applied to production, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know what date that revision was actually applied to
>   production, is this possible?

Note that Apache Subversion is a version-control system, it's not a deployment or build machine that may have a separate log of what exactly was deployed. Moreover, it's impossible to answer your question precisely without knowing a lot of details such as how you use Subversion and how you deploy the changes.

If the revision in question had been merged in 2014 to the trunk or the branch you recently deployed to production, then it had always been there. However, if it was merged by some reason a short time ago, then I guess that the change made it with your recent deployment.

Check the history of your changes. There is a chance that your changes contain the 2014-year changes just because of some mistake.

Read [SVNBook | Examining History](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.history.html#svn.tour.history.diff) and don't forget to use [`svn blame`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html). Since you are using TortoiseSVN, check [TortoiseSVN Manual | Who Changed Which Line?](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-blame.html).